# ScrollPane making "AJAX ERROR" alert

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

i'm with a problem here: http://thehitz.com.br/loja.php

when the page loads, appears an AJAX ERROR alert but the script works. That alert only shows up when i put the javascript code in the html. I've looked into the code and tried to localize the factor that is making this annoing thing happen but didnt have luck on it. Help me, please.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            // the element we want to apply the jScrollPane
            var $el                 = $('#conteudo-container').jScrollPane({
                verticalGutter  : -16
            }),

            // the extension functions and options  
                extensionPlugin     = {

                    extPluginOpts   : {
                        // speed for the fadeOut animation
                        mouseLeaveFadeSpeed : 500,
                        // scrollbar fades out after hovertimeout_t milliseconds
                        hovertimeout_t      : 1000,
                        // if set to false, the scrollbar will be shown on mouseenter and hidden on mouseleave
                        // if set to true, the same will happen, but the scrollbar will be also hidden on mouseenter after "hovertimeout_t" ms
                        // also, it will be shown when we start to scroll and hidden when stopping
                        useTimeout          : false,
                        // the extension only applies for devices with width > deviceWidth
                        deviceWidth         : 980
                    },
                    hovertimeout    : null, // timeout to hide the scrollbar
                    isScrollbarHover: false,// true if the mouse is over the scrollbar
                    elementtimeout  : null, // avoids showing the scrollbar when moving from inside the element to outside, passing over the scrollbar
                    isScrolling     : false,// true if scrolling
                    addHoverFunc    : function() {

                        // run only if the window has a width bigger than deviceWidth
                        if( $(window).width() <= this.extPluginOpts.deviceWidth ) return false;

                        var instance        = this;

                        // functions to show / hide the scrollbar
                        $.fn.jspmouseenter  = $.fn.show;
                        $.fn.jspmouseleave  = $.fn.fadeOut;

                        // hide the jScrollPane vertical bar
                        var $vBar           = this.getContentPane().siblings('.jspVerticalBar').hide();

                        /*
                         * mouseenter / mouseleave events on the main element
                         * also scrollstart / scrollstop - @James Padolsey : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/
                         */
                        $el.bind('mouseenter.jsp',function() {

                            // show the scrollbar
                            $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();

                            if( !instance.extPluginOpts.useTimeout ) return false;

                            // hide the scrollbar after hovertimeout_t ms
                            clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                            instance.hovertimeout   = setTimeout(function() {
                                // if scrolling at the moment don't hide it
                                if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                            }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );


                        }).bind('mouseleave.jsp',function() {

                            // hide the scrollbar
                            if( !instance.extPluginOpts.useTimeout )
                                $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                            else {
                            clearTimeout( instance.elementtimeout );
                            if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                            }

                        });

                        if( this.extPluginOpts.useTimeout ) {

                            $el.bind('scrollstart.jsp', function() {

                                // when scrolling show the scrollbar
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrolling    = true;
                                $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();

                            }).bind('scrollstop.jsp', function() {

                                // when stop scrolling hide the scrollbar (if not hovering it at the moment)
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrolling    = false;
                                instance.hovertimeout   = setTimeout(function() {
                                    if( !instance.isScrollbarHover )
                                        $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );

                            });

                            // wrap the scrollbar
                            // we need this to be able to add the mouseenter / mouseleave events to the scrollbar
                            var $vBarWrapper    = $('<div/>').css({
                                position    : 'absolute',
                                left        : $vBar.css('left'),
                                top         : $vBar.css('top'),
                                right       : $vBar.css('right'),
                                bottom      : $vBar.css('bottom'),
                                width       : $vBar.width(),
                                height      : $vBar.height()
                            }).bind('mouseenter.jsp',function() {

                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                clearTimeout( instance.elementtimeout );

                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = true;

                                // show the scrollbar after 100 ms.
                                // avoids showing the scrollbar when moving from inside the element to outside, passing over the scrollbar                              
                                instance.elementtimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();
                                }, 100 );   

                            }).bind('mouseleave.jsp',function() {

                                // hide the scrollbar after hovertimeout_t
                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = false;
                                instance.hovertimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                    // if scrolling at the moment don't hide it
                                    if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                        $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );

                            });

                            $vBar.wrap( $vBarWrapper );

                        }

                    }

                },

                // the jScrollPane instance
                jspapi          = $el.data('jsp');

            // extend the jScollPane by merging 
            $.extend( true, jspapi, extensionPlugin );
            jspapi.addHoverFunc();

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look at the console, you can see that there is a Ajax post request that is failing:

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://thehitz.com.br/jcart/js/jcart.min.js"
```